# how to disable depth test but enable update depth texture(like glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)) in metal?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, metal

In OpenGL, we can disable depth test and only update depth texture(the depth texture is bind to `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` of FBO by `glFramebufferTexture2D`) in the following ways:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
```

`glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` means all the fragments will "always pass", so I set `MTLCompareFunctionAlways` to `depthCompareFunction` of `MTLDepthStencilDescriptor`.

`glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)` means the depth texture will be updated with the fragments depth value, whatever value it previously had. In Metal, I set `true` to `depthWriteEnabled` of `MTLDepthStencilDescriptor`.

Unfortunately, the final render result is wrong. Is that I understand it wrong? If yes, then how to set it in the correct way in Metal.

Comment: What you've described sounds right. You'll have to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the depth buffer exists and the depth mask is non-zero, the depth buffer is not updated if the depth test is disabled. In order to unconditionally write to the depth buffer, the depth test should be enabled and set to `GL_ALWAYS` by `glDepthFunc`.

Comment: He wants the Metal code; not the OpenGL code.